# Как обновить Активити или Фрагмент из Адаптара?

Tags: java, android, adapter

Как обновить Активити или Фрагмент из Адаптара?
`recreate();` или `getActivity().recreate();` Здесь не работает.

При нажатии на пункт списка, в адаптаре прописан код удаления этого объекта из БД. Так вот если нажать на любой пункт, объект удаляется из БД, но чтобы увидеть что его нет, нужно выйти и войти, другими словами перезагрузить

Comment: Вам нужно обновлять не все активити, а только виджет списка (recyclerview/listview) для этого в адаптере есть методы, начирающиеся на notify..

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего для вас подойдет [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) + [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), данные обновятся при изменении  в базе.

Comment: Я испоьзую ORM Sugar,  CursorLoader я так понял для SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `notifyDataSetChanged ()` после удаления

Comment: Я попробовал, но не выходит

Comment: А вы перед notifyDataSetChanged удалённую запись из базы, из массива, из которого данные для отображения берете, удаляете?

Comment: В активити я загружаются, данные в list, затем list загружаются в адаптар, в адаптар уже удаляю из БД, я так понял, лучше в адаптар загружать напрямую из БД, но нужно переписать саму архитектуру. Пока думаю как лучше это сделать. Я так понял, что через адаптар перезагрузить фрагмент нельзя?

Comment: В самом фрагменте, я после добавлении в БД пишу getActivity().recreate(); Фрагмент обновляется и появляется новый пункт в списке. Проблема в том, что у меня не одна таблица в БД, а 49 и в зависимости от того какие данные получает фрагмент заполняется определенная таблица. А так если была бы одна таблица, то ее можно было просто напрямую отправить в адаптар

Comment: Удалять лучше не в адаптере, а в активити, после удаления перечитать данные в list, передать адаптеру новый список (через сеттер), после этого вызвать notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Лучше использовать notifyItemRemoved, удаляете запись из базы, удаляете из списка в адаптере, вызываете notifyItemRemoved.